# Scala try with finally best practice

Tags: scala, exception

I have the following implementation where I'm trying to handle proper resource closing during any fatal exceptions:

```
  private def loadPrivateKey(keyPath: String) = {
    def tryReadCertificate(file: File): Try[BufferedReader] = Try { new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)) }

    def tryLoadPemParser(reader: BufferedReader): Try[PEMParser] = Try { new PEMParser(reader) }

    def createXXX(buffReader: BufferedReader, pemParser: PEMParser) = try {
     ...  
    } finally {
      buffReader.close()
      pemParser.close()
    }
    tryReadCertificate(new File(keyPath, "myKey.pem")) match {
      case Success(buffReader) => tryLoadPemParser(buffReader) match {
        case Success(pemParser) => createXXX(buffReader, pemParser)
        case Failure(fail) =>
      }
      case Failure(fail) =>
    }
  }
```

I already see that my nested case blocks are a mess. Is there a better way to do this? In the end, I just want to make sure that I close the `BufferedReader` and the `PEMParser`    !

Comment: `Try` makes most sense when it's the type you want to return in your API for whatever reason instead of exceptions. It seems this example doesn't use any features of `Try` so the simplest solution would be not to use it. Otherwise, don't use it in your inner functions but only around the outer expression.

Comment: Possibly not the answer you're after, but I'd say best practice is to use [scala-arm](https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm).

Comment: I do not want to use scala-arm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could restructure your code a little like this, using a for-comprehension to clean up some of the nested case statements:

```
def tryReadCertificate(file: File): Try[BufferedReader] = Try { new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)) }

def tryLoadPemParser(reader: BufferedReader): Try[PEMParser] = Try { new PEMParser(reader) }

def createXXX(buffReader: BufferedReader, pemParser: PEMParser) = {
  ...
}

val certReaderTry = tryReadCertificate(new File(keyPath, "myKey.pem"))
val pemParserTry = for{
  certReader <- certReaderTry
  pemParser <- tryLoadPemParser(certReader)
} yield {
  createXXX(certReader, pemParser)
  pemParser
}

certReaderTry foreach(_.close)
pemParserTry foreach (_.close)
```

Structured like this, you will only ever end up calling close on things you are sure were opened successfully.

And even better, if your `PEMParser` happened to extend `java.io.Closeable`, meaning that the `Try`s both wrapped `Closeable` objects, then you could swap those last two lines for a single line like this:

```
(certReaderTry.toOption ++ pemParserTry.toOption) foreach (_.close)
```

**EDIT**

In response to the OP's comment: In the first example, if `tryreadCertificate` succeeds, then `certReaderTry` will be a `Success[BufferedReader]` and because it's successful, calling `foreach` on it will yield the `BufferedReader` which will then have close called on it.  If `certReaderTry` is `Success`, then (via the for-comp) we will call `tryLoadPemParser` and if that also succeeds, we can move on to `createXXX` and assign the `tryLoadPemParser` to the `pemParserTry` `val`.  Then, later, if `pemParserTry` is a `Success`, the same thing happens where `foreach` yields the `PEMParser` and we can close it.  Per this example, as long as the those `Try`s are successes and something else unexpected does not happen (in `createXXX` for example) that would throw an exception all the way out, then you can guarantee that the closing related code at the end will do its job and close those resources.

**EDIT2**

If you wanted the value from `createXXX` in a separate `Try`, then you could do something like this:

```
val certReaderTry = tryReadCertificate(new File(keyPath, "myKey.pem"))
val pemParserTry = certReaderTry.flatMap(tryLoadPemParser)
val resultTry = for{
  certReader <- certReaderTry
  pemParser <- pemParserTry
} yield createXXX(certReader, pemParser)
```

Comment: How is the close method guaranteed to run?

Comment: Would be nice if whoever downvoted provided a comment as to why

Comment: @user3102968, I edited my answer to provide more detail.

Comment: Ok. Waht if I wanted to return the value from my createXXX(...) method? I have to return a tuple?

Comment: @user3102968, updated again with how you could accomplish that